# Connecting Dots

Tags: code-golf

## Connecting Dots

### We define a type of question on the test, connecting the dots

#### Question parameters

There are two parameters. Suppose they are `5` and `4`. The second one **must be less than or equal to the first one**.

Thus, the question will look like this:

```
*
         *
*
         *
*
         *
*
         *
*
```

#### Possible answers

An answer is termed `logically possible` if and only if:

- Each dot on the left corresponds to one and only one dot on the right
- Each dot on the right corresponds to at least one dot on the left (there is no maximum)

#### We describe an answer using a `matrix`, or `list of lists`.

For instance, `[[0,0],[1,0],[2,1]]` will link the dot indexed 0 on the left to the dot indexed 0 on the right, et cetera. You may choose to use 0-indexed or 1-indexed.

#### We define an answer's `complexity`...

...as the number of intersections there are. For instance, the complexity of the answer `[[0,2],[1,1],[2,0]]` to be `1` as they intersect at the same point (assuming they are **evenly spaced out**).

## Purpose

- Calculate the complexity of a given solution

## Grading

This is **`code golf`**.

Comment: So, the number of surjective functions?

Comment: I searched... Yeah, sort of...

Comment: Can we say that the output is the number of (distinct) **surjective** functions `f: A -> B`, where the cardinality of `A` and `B` are respectively the question parameters?

Comment: I think so, but I am not quite fluent with "subjective functions".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function

Comment: "[The output] will not appear" seems a strict requirement, what if my answer is a C function which ouputs the result via the return value?

Comment: Please note that "an input will not appear" usually means the input falls into *don't care* situation.

Comment: Yep, so you may output whatever you like. If you want to you can output the lyrics of NGGYU but I just don't understand why ;-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 17 bytes

```
#2!StirlingS2@##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@1/ZSDG4JLMoJzMvPdjIQVlZ7X9AUWZeiYK@g4JjUVFiZXSajkK1hY6CRa2OgkHsfwA)

This is [OEIS A019538](http://oeis.org/A019538).

Comment: First time I've ever seen THAT builtin...

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 42 bytes

```c
f(a,b){return a--?b*(f(a,b)+f(a,b-1)):!b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BDoIwEEXX7SkGDEkr1GhiYiKiF3EDBXSIFlNhBZwdW0HFjc7mp5N5fV@Kk5R9n7M4SHijs6rWCmIhDsmcDUv/GWLF@dZJwq6foZKXOs1gd69SLBfnPUVVwTVGxThtKLlp886ZC63LQ0ryUgOzFwVEsAxNOBFsTPo@pzCZN@et0Q2gsPBrd1TCF//nW4iDEEchWiExBSe/etgaFVrsd1HyocZ@OcOg4JbsaNc/AA)

This uses a recurrence relation. Let \$f(a,b)\$ be the number of answers for \$a\$ left dots and \$b\$ right dots.

Consider the first left dot; it is joined to one right dot, with \$b\$ possibilities.

- If that right dot is joined to at least one other left dot, then the remaining \$a-1\$ left dots cover the \$b\$ right dots at least once each, for \$f(a-1,b)\$ possibilities.
- If that right dot is not joined to any other left dot, then the remaining \$a-1\$ left dots cover the \$b-1\$ other right dots at least once each, for \$f(a-1,b-1)\$ possibilities.

Therefore, \$ f(a,b) = b \times (f(a-1,b) + f(a-1,b-1)) \$.

The base case is \$ f(0,0) = 1\$ and \$ f(0,b) = 0\$ for \$ b > 0 \$.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LIãεÙg¹Q}O
```

Two loose inputs in reversed order.

Port of [*@MatteoC.*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247126/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fx/Pw4nNbD89MP7QzsNb//39jLhMA) or [verify all test cases below 6](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W96bJLfoZUgMvTQuohHDbPslRQetU1SULIHcv/7HFp3ePG5rYdnpkcE1vr/1/kPAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
          #  E.g. inputs: b=2,a=3
L         # Push a list in the range [1, first (implicit) input `b`]
          #  → [1,2]
 Iã       # Create all possible `a`-sized combinations from this list, using the
          # cartesian product
          #  → [[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,2],[2,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[2,2,2]]
   ε      # Map over each inner list:
    Ù     #  Uniquify it
          #   → [[1],[1,2],[1,2],[1,2],[2,1],[2,1],[2,1],[2]]
     g    #  Pop and push the length to get the amount of unique values
          #   → [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,1]
      ¹Q  #  Check if its equal to the first input `b`
          #   → [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
   }O     # After the map: check how many were truthy by taking the sum
          #  → 6
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>97</s> <s>95</s> <s>88</s> 84 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to [@Number Basher](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/111945/number-basher)*

*-4 bytes thanks to [@Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)*

```
from itertools import*
f=lambda a,b:sum(b==len({*x})for x in product(*[range(b)]*a))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY6xDoIwFEV3vqLja1MHYTEk_IUbYWiFahPa1zweCcb4JS4s-k_-jSWRO9zpnJv7-qQ73zCu63tmdzh9z44wCM8DMeI4CR8SEqvCNaMJtjfCaFtPcwDbNOMQ4aGWp3RIYhE-ikTYzxcG1ZKJ1wGs7JSR8r993Ljsb2QLpa6khkqXucvcXV2InEQ-MjjI3C7u534)

Comment: That's good!!! I especially like it because if the input is `[2,3]` or invalid, it gives out `0` which is sensible.

Comment: Check this out, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python/247083?noredirect=1#comment553173_247083.

Comment: in short, you can use `[*{*x}]==b` instead of `len(set(x))==b`, which saves 4 bytes.

Comment: Watch carefully the tip you linked and what's needed in this context

Comment: Oops, I missed that, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, do you really need the `x` in `len([x for`? consider a way to improve that!

Comment: `range(b),repeat=a` can be `*[range(b)]*a` for -4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 7 bytes

```
ɾ↔vUvL=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJzIiwiIiwiyb7ihpR2VXZMPSIsIiIsIjNcbjQiXQ==) or [Run all the test cases below 6](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCJAZjoyfCIsIjrJviTiiIfihpR2VXZMPeKIkSIsIjtcblxuNTrhuopzOsabw7dAZjs7WsabYCA9PiBgajvigYsiLCIiXQ==)

### How?

```
ɾ↔vUvL=
ɾ       # List in the range [1, (implicit) first input `b`]
 ↔      # Get all possible combinations of this list of size (implicit) second input `a`
  vU    # For each item, uniquify
    vL  # For each item, get the length
      = # Is each item equal to the (implicit) first input `b`?
        # `s` flag sums the top of the stack
```

Other 7-byters:

```
ɾ↔ƛUL;=
ɾ↔ƛUL¹=
```

#### Flagless:

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ɾ↔vUvL=∑
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvuKGlHZVdkw94oiRIiwiIiwiM1xuNCJd)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 23 bytes

```
Ｆ⊕η⊞υ¬ιＦＮＵＭυ×λ⁺κ§υ⊖λＩ⊟υ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rcy9DgIhEATg/p6Cckmw0fIqczZXeKHwBRDWQOTnArvGt0dJTJxy5stYb6otJvb@KFXAmm3FhJnQgZdSaG4eWImtEAQp5@mndqaN0x0rfNHV7EtJyWQ36C0kbBCV0JEbPJU405odvsd2wf99lCPzpGvIBItpBLrswKPs/SSO/fCKHw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ⊕η⊞υ¬ι
```

Create a list of one `1` and `k` `0`s corresponding to a 0-indexed first row of the table in OEIS linked by @alephalpha.

```
ＦＮ
```

Repeat `n` times:

```
ＵＭυ×λ⁺κ§υ⊖λ
```

Update the row using the recurrence relation given in OEIS but also @m90's answer.

```
Ｉ⊟υ
```

Output the last value calculated.